# Missing class LiveDataReactiveStreams

Tags: java, android, rx-java2, android-architecture-components

I am trying to use new Android Architecture Components. I'dd like to convert Rx Flowable to LiveData with [LiveDataReactiveStreams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams.html) but the class is missing.

Here are my dependencies:

`compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1"
 compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha1"
 kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha1"`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're missing this dependency:

`implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.0.0-beta2"`

Answer (score 2):

FYI: there's a new version:

```
implementation  'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
```

Also, the link in the original post is pointing to the deprecated version, now I would be ideal to use the next package:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveDataReactiveStreams
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveDataReactiveStreams